# How can I distinguish between two different users who live near to each other?

Tags: probability, signature

How can I distinguish between two different users, like two different neighbours who lives in a same address and goes to the same office, but they have different patterns of driving and have different office schedules. I wanted to find out the probability of two persons who behaves more or less exactly. Depending on the resolution of the map, I wants to figure them, where they are, how often they are. Can I create a pattern ´for each drivers into some signatures, where their identity can be traced upon.

Comment: In what language exactly?

Comment: @imulsion This question is more about statistics and algorithms than it is about a language to express it.

Comment: I dn't use any language as of now, but working on this idea. This topic is based on Vanet Security.

Comment: then I would recommend math.stackexchange.com ? I don't really see what this has to do with programming

Comment: yea, there is nothing to do with programming section, but with logical and mathematical reasoning.

Comment: I don't know whether this will fit on [math.se] (@imulsion). This looks like a typical [tag:algorithm] question to me (though it needs quite a bit of work). What exactly does the data you currently have look like? And by "behaving the same", do you roughly mean "go to the exact same places at the exact same times"? And what exactly is the relation in rate of probability supposed to be between distance and time? For example, is 2 miles closer than 4 hours? Also, is  driving roughly the same route to different places closer than different routes to same place? And what would a 0 probability be?

Comment: "By behaving the same" refers to two neighbours,who goes to the same place, but at different times..For example, both the neighbours unfortunatley works in the same office, but both follows different time intervals and different travel pattern to reach their office.

Comment: So, from what you say, I assume a 100% similarity is when 1 person has exactly the same hours as someone else, just shifted by a few hours (so person1 = 8AM-5PM => +2 hours => person2 = 10AM-7PM => 100% similar), is that right? Also, what data are you working with? Is it physical map coordinates with times or is it simply arrive and departure times at work / home? Do you already have 2 neighbors going to the same office or do you have a bunch of people living and working anywhere and you have to find all the neighbors that work at the same offices?

Comment: You guessed it right. The assumptions of both the persons with the time interval are right, just shifted by a few hours. I'm working with the physical co-ordinates, both the people carrying a gps enabled mobile device, when they move between home and office, so their data's are captured. I already have data's of two different people who goes to the same place. I used tracemymap and google latitude to see the various paths’s taken by these two individuals. Now my aim is to get a signature of each individual and compare them by using cryptographic techniques.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure whether this is an algorithm question any more (well, if you want to do this programmatically it might be). Perhaps [stats.se] would be a good fit (assuming the question is modified to tend to the questions I asked).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll definitely have a look into cross validated stuffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, by the way that you asked your question, that you haven't had any plausible ideas yet.  So I'll make an answer which is purely based on an idea that you might like to try out.

I initially thought of suggesting something along the line of word-similarity metrics, but because order is not necessarily important here, maybe it's worth trying something simpler to start.  In fact, if I ever find myself considering something complex when developing a model, I take a step back and try to simplify.  It's quicker to code, and you don't get so attached to something that's a dead end.

So, how about histograms?  If you divide up time and space into larger blocks, you can increment a value in the relevant location for each time interval.  You get a 2D histogram of a person's location.  You can use basic anti-aliasing to make the histograms more representative.

From there, it's down to histogram comparison.  You could implement something real basic using only 1D strips.  You know, like sum the similarity measure for each of the vertical and horizontal strips.  Linear histogram comparison is super-easy, and just a few lines of code in a language like C.  Good enough for proof of concept.  If it feels you're on the right track, then start looking for more tricky ideas...

The next thing I'd do is further stratify my data, using days of the week and statutory holidays...  Maybe even stratify further using seasonal variables.  I've found it pretty effective for forecasting electricity load, which is as much about social patterns as it is about weather.  The trends become much more distinct when you separate an influencing variable.

So, after stratification you get a stack of 2D 'slices', and your signature becomes a kind of 3D volume.  I see nothing wrong with representing the entire planet as a grid.  Whether your squares represent 100m or 1km.  It's easy to store this sparsely and prune out anything that's outside some number of standard deviations.  You might choose only the most major events for the day and end up with a handful of locations.

You can then focus on the comparison metric.  Maybe some kind of image-based gradient- or cluster-analysis.  I'm sure there's loads of really great stuff out there.  This is just the kinds of starting-points I make, having done no research.

If you need to add some temporal information to introduce separation between people with very similar lives, you can maybe build some lags into the system...  Such as "where they were an hour ago".  At that point (or possibly before), you probably want to switch from my over-simplified approach of averaging out a person's daily activities, and instead use something like classification trees.  This kind of thing is very easy and rapid to develop with a tool like MATLAB or R.

Comment: Thanks for your great response. When I initially thought about representation of data, I thought about binning my data and representing in a histogram format. As you mentioned before, in binning the whole locality is divided into different polygon and represented into a histogram format. I was really struck with the comparison metrics and reducing each individual identity to a signature.

Comment: I don't understand the term " after stratification you get a stack of 2D 'slices', and your signature becomes a kind of 3D volume" Can you briefly elaborate on this part?

Comment: Sure...  Essentially you break your data up into groups based on some variable.  Day-of-week is an obvious one, as you would expect a person's behavioural patterns to be different - at least on work days versus weekends, if not individual days.  So you build a separate histogram for each day.  If your histogram is a grid, you can imagine each histogram stacked up and showing the variations in pattern.  At that point you decide how you want to compare histograms.  Normally you would only compare sundays with sundays, but your task may be different - someone might have a different 'weekend'.